# Error in a * b * y : non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

```
Cold <- matrix(c(1.89,3.76,2.47,4.76),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
X <- matrix(c(0,2,2,4,3,6),3,2,byrow=TRUE)
y <- matrix(c(1,5,6))

m <- 2;
R <- 2;
Ec <- 0.001;
p <- 1/(m-1)

C <- mat.or.vec(R,R)
M <- length(X[,1])
mu <- mat.or.vec(M,R)
#mu=matrix(,M,R)
Q1=0;Q2=0;
pl <- 1/(m-1)
F=0;
it <- 0;
ph <- 1;


repeat
{




####################
for (i in 1:M)
{
for (j in 1:R)
{
Q1=0;Q2=0;F=0
Q1 <- sum((X[i,]-Cold[j,])^2)
for (k in 1:R)
{
Q2 <- sum((X[i,]-Cold[k,])^2)
F=Q1/Q2+F
}
mu[i,j] <- solve(F)
}
}


####################






##########centre Update
B=mat.or.vec(1,2);
for (j in 1:R)
{
A=mat.or.vec(1,2);
for (i in 1:M)
{
A=X[i,]*mu[i,j]^m+A

#C=(t(mu)*X)/colSums(mu)
}
B=colSums(mu^m)
C[j,] <- A/B[j];
}
#########centre update end



ph <- abs(sqrt(sum((C - Cold)^2)))
Cold <- C
##################
if(ph < Ec)  
{
break;
}
it <- it+1
}
##################


X
plot(X[,1],X[,2],pch=5,lwd=6,col = "blue",cex = .6)
for(i in 1:length(C[,1]))
{
points(C[i,1],C[i,2],pch=4,lwd=4)       
}

library(MASS)

w <- rep(1,nrow(X))
X <- cbind(w,X)
X <- as.matrix(X)
para <-  mat.or.vec(3,R)
 #i<-0

h <- mat.or.vec(3,3)
a <- mat.or.vec(3,3)
b <- mat.or.vec(3,3)
for(i in 1:R)
#while (i<3)
{
h <- t(X)*(diag(mu[,i]))^2*X
a <- solve(t(X)*(diag(mu[,i]))^2*X)
b <- (t(X)*diag(mu[,i])^2)
para[,i] <- a*b*y
}
```

> This is the code for clustering, it clusters the data and it works nice  but it gives me >an error in the end part of calculating rule consequents, it is finally taking a toll on >me.It shows the error "Error in a * b * y : non-conformable arrays", Can anyone help me >please?

Comment: The code that you've included in the question runs fine.  I don't get an error about non-conformable arrays.  So that this question is useful to future readers, please edit it so that the rror actually gets generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "conformable arrays" is linear algebra jargon that means "arrays that can sensibly be operated on together".

For example, if you want to add two arrays together, they need to be the same size.

In fact, since the standard math operators, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, etc. operate element-by-element, you always need the arrays (or matrices) to be the same size.

For (inner) matrix multiplication, `%*%`, the number of columns in the first matrix must be the same as the number of rows in the second matrix.

Comment: Thanks Richie , i got your point.

Comment: But can you or anyone tell how can i make my poor coding some better.

Comment: @ALIKHAN You can improve your coding by reading books on R (and good programming practice), by reading other people's code, and by writing lots of code yourself.  There is no magic solution; like any skill, it just takes effort.